# Predictive distribution for gamma likelihood and prior

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, bayesian, gamma-distribution

*For the following problem, I’m **stuck at the 3rd question**.
I would appreciate if you could validate my answer to the 1st question as well.*

##### Problem

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2, \theta)$ with support $(0, \infty)$ and p.d.f.
$$f(x | \theta) = \theta^2 x e^{-\theta x}$$
Let $\operatorname{Gamma}(2, \lambda)$ where $\lambda > 0$ be the prior distribution of $\theta$ with support $(0, \infty)$ and p.d.f.
$$g(\theta) = \lambda^2 \theta e^{-\lambda\theta}$$

1. Identify the posterior density function $g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of $\theta$ given data $X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_n = x_n$.
2. Determine the Bayesian estimator $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$ under the square loss function.
3. Determine the predictive density of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_n = x_n$, namely $f(x_{n+1} | x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

##### Answer

1. According to the Bayes theorem,
   \begin{align*}
   g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)
   &= \frac{f(x_1, \dots, x_n | \theta) g(\theta)}{f(x_1, \dots, x_n)}
   = g(\theta) \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \theta)}{\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}
   \end{align*}
   The marginal density of the data is hard to determine.
   It would likely require three integrations by parts.
   $$
   f(x_i)
   = \int_0^\infty {f(x_i | \theta) g(\theta)}{d\theta}
   = \int_0^\infty {\lambda^2 x_i \theta^3 e^{-(\lambda+x_i)\theta}}{d\theta}
   $$
   However, it is constant w.r.t. to $\theta$, so we can write
   \begin{align*}
   g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)
   &\propto f(x_1, \dots, x_n | \theta) g(\theta)
   \\&= \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \theta^2 x_i e^{-\theta x_i} \right) \lambda^2 \theta e^{-\lambda \theta}
   \\&\propto \theta^{2n+1} e^{-(\lambda +  n \bar{x}) \theta}
   \end{align*}
   It seems to be the p.d.f of $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha = 2(n+1), \beta = \lambda+n\bar{x})$, that is
   \begin{align*}
   g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)
   &= \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \theta^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta \theta}
   = \frac{(\lambda+n\bar{x})^{2(n+1)}}{(2n+1)!} \theta^{2n+1} e^{-(\lambda+n\bar{x}) \theta}
   \end{align*}
   *Note: [That exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3992755/663478) seems to validate the approach.*
2. The Bayes estimator minimizes the posterior expected loss.
   For the squared loss, it is
   \begin{align*}
        \hat\theta(x_1, \dots, x_n)
        &= \mathbb{E}[{\theta | X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_n = x_n}]
   \end{align*}
   The expectation of $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ is $\alpha / \beta$, so
   $$\hat\theta(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{2(n+1)}{\lambda + n \bar{x}}$$
3. The predictive density is
   \begin{align*}
   f(x_{n+1} | x_1, \dots, x_n)
   &= \int_0^\infty {f(x_{n+1} | \theta) g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)} d\theta
   \\&= \int_0^\infty{\theta^2 x_{n+1} e^{-\theta x_{n+1}} \cdot \frac{(\lambda + n\bar{x})^{2(n+1)}}{(2n+1)!} \theta^{2n+1} e^{-(\lambda + n \bar{x}) \theta}} d\theta
   \\&= \frac{x_{n+1} (\lambda + n\bar{x})^{2(n+1)}}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^\infty {\theta^{2(n+1)+1} e^{-(\lambda + n \bar{x} + x_{n+1}) \theta}} d\theta
   \\&= \mathbf{?}
   \end{align*}
   *The function inside the integral seems to be $k$ times the p.d.f. of $\operatorname{Gamma}(2(n+2), \lambda + n \bar{x} + x_{n+1})$ with $k > 0$.
   Should I go on with this idea, noticing that the integral should equal a constant (total probabilities w.r.t. $\theta$), and find the $k$ that makes everything coherent?
   Or are there some conjugacy properties to leverage?*

*Thank you very much for your help.*

Comment: I think you can *"go on with this idea"*.   Alternatively,  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) seems to suggest that with a Gamma likelihood where the shape is known (here $2$) and a Gamma prior, the predictive distribution is a [generalised Beta prime / compound Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Compound_gamma_distribution) but I doubt that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

Let $\alpha_k = 2(k+1)$ and $\beta_k = \lambda + k \bar x_k = \lambda + \sum_{i=1}^n x_k$.
The predictive density is
\begin{align*}
f(x_{n+1} | x_1, \dots, x_n)
&= \int_0^\infty {f(x_{n+1} | \theta) g(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_n)}{d\theta}
\\&= \int_0^\infty {\theta^2 x_{n+1} e^{-\theta x_{n+1}} \frac{\beta_n^{\alpha_n}}{(\alpha_n-1)!} \theta^{\alpha_n-1} e^{-\beta_n \theta}}{d\theta}
\\&= \frac{\beta_n^{\alpha_n}}{(\alpha_n-1)!} x_{n+1} \int_0^\infty {\theta^{2(n+1)+1} e^{-(\lambda + n \bar{x}_n + x_{n+1}) \theta}}{d\theta}
\\&= x_{n+1} \frac{\beta_n^{\alpha_n}}{(\alpha_n-1)!} \int_0^\infty {\theta^{\alpha_{n+1}-1} e^{-\beta_{n+1} \theta}}{d\theta}
\end{align*}
The expression inside the integral has the shape of the p.d.f. of $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha_{n+1}, \beta_{n+1})$:
\begin{align*}
h(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}) = \frac{\beta_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}}}{(\alpha_{n+1}-1)!} \theta^{\alpha_{n+1}-1} e^{-\beta_{n+1} \theta}
\end{align*}
By the law of total probabilities,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty {h(\theta | x_1, \dots, x_{n+1})}{d\theta}
&= 1
\\ \iff
\int_0^\infty{\theta^{\alpha_{n+1}-1} e^{-\beta_{n+1} \theta}}{d\theta} &= \frac{(\alpha_{n+1}-1)!}{\beta_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}}}
\\\\ \implies
f(x_{n+1} | x_1, \dots, x_n)
&= x_{n+1} \frac{\beta_n^{\alpha_n}}{(\alpha_n-1)!} \frac{(\alpha_{n+1}-1)!}{\beta_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}}}
\\&= \frac{(\alpha_{n+1}-1)!}{(\alpha_n-1)!} \frac{\beta_n^{\alpha_n}}{\beta_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}}} x_{n+1}
\\&= \frac{(2n+3)!}{(2n+1)!} \frac{(\lambda + n\bar{x}_n)^{2(n+1)}}{(\lambda + (n+1) \bar x_{n+1})^{2(n+2)}} x_{n+1}
\\&= (2n+2)(2n+3) \left( \frac{\lambda + n\bar{x}_n}{\lambda + (n+1) \bar x_{n+1}} \right)^{2(n+1)} \frac{x_{n+1}}{(\lambda + (n+1) \bar x_{n+1})^2}
\\&= \frac{(2n+2)(2n+3) x_{n+1}}{(\lambda + (n+1) \bar x_{n+1})^2} \left( 1 - \frac{x_{n+1}}{\lambda + (n+1) \bar x_{n+1}} \right)^{2(n+1)}
\end{align*}